# Swift How to know if layout finished after layoutIfNeeded()

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview

I have a mathematical program for the iPad using a Big Number library that does calculations, and then updates an array of up to 20,000 UILabels in a UIView (myView) based on those calculations.

The calculations can take about 5 seconds, during which time the backgroundColor of each of the UILabels is set to a color.   Because nothing is happening on the screen, I have a blinking UILabel inProgressLabel that informs the user that the system is calculating.  I then call layoutIfNeeded, with the idea that when it is finished, the screen will have been updated.   Finally, I turn off the blinking UILabel.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
inProgressLabel.turnOnBlinking()

for row in 0..<rowCount
{

    for col in 0..<colCount
    {

        // perform some calculation
        let z = buttonArray[row][col].performCalculation() 


        //now set the Label background based on the result of the calculation
        buttonArray[row][col].setLabelBackground(z)
    }

}

myView.layoutIfNeeded()   

inProgressLabel.turnOffBlinking()
```

My understanding was the layoutIfNeeded() is synchronous.   Thus, the screen will update and then, and only then, the blinking inProgressLabel will be turned off.   However, the inProgressLabel is actually turning off immediately after layoutIfNeeded is called, and then it can take another five seconds for the array of UILabels to update.

I thought that maybe this is happening because the updating is occurring in a different thread.   If this is so, is there a way to know for sure when the UIView, and the array of UILabels, have finished updating (displaying), so that I can then turn off the blinking UILabel?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for row in 0..<rowCount
{

    for col in 0..<colCount
    {

        dispatchGroup.enter()

        self.doCalcAndUpdateLbl(index: i) { (finish) in

            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

    myView.layoutIfNeeded()

    inProgressLabel.turnOffBlinking()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UIKit controls are not thread-safe. Updating UILabels from the background produces undefined behaviour.

`layoutIfNeeded` performs any pending layout tasks and returns. It has no magical foresight of any changes you may be planning to make in the future.

You need to schedule your work to occur off the main queue, and ensure results are pushed back to the main thread when done. If it makes sense to dispatch various calculations to occur separately, use a dispatch group as Sh_Khan suggests. Otherwise consider just performing the background calculations in a single block and hopping back onto the main queue from there.

It's also highly unlikely that 20,000 UILabels is appropriate; look into using a table view or a collection view. As a general rule, you should try to have active controls only for whatever is presently on screen, and both of those views offer ways very easily to manage that active set. Every view has a memory footprint because the content of views is buffered — you'll hurt your own performance and that of other running applications if you unnecessarily squeeze memory.